# Name and representation of isometries in $\Bbb R ^4$

Tags: group-theory, isometry

This is a question about appropriate naming and representation.

What are the classes of isometries in $\Bbb R ^4$?

I can easily identify the rotation around a plan, the reflection through an infinite flat volume (any $\Bbb R ^3$ space orthogonal to a vector). What is the complete set of isometries classes?

What is the appropriate name of what I improperly named here a "class" of isometries?

What is the best graphical representation of these classes of isometries?

Comment: The mathematical description is the isometry group $E(4)=O_4(\Bbb R)\ltimes \Bbb R^4$, where $O_4(\Bbb R)$ is the orthogonal group and $\Bbb R^4$ is the abelian group consisting of translations. The group is the semidirect product of the "orthogonal" motions and the translations.

Comment: It is not even clear what a classification means for elements of $O(4)$ (linear parts of affine isometries of $R^4$). One can classify them for instance by the sizes of their Jordan blocks (partitions of $4$). Maybe this is what you are interested in.  Incidentally, "inversion around a volume" makes no sense. I suspect you mean "an isometric involution fixing a hyperplane." How much Linear Algebra do you know? Do you know about [Jordan Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)?

Comment: About the "inversion around a volume" I wanted to name the equivalent of the symmetry through a plan in $\Bbb R ^3$ I tried to improve my OQ. I think your naming is the right one. Thank you for the notion of Jordan blocks I am starting to grasp now.